# Geolocation is not working on my mobile device (USER DENIED GEOLOCATION) - Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geolocation

I have the `Openlayers 3 Geolocation API` working on non-mobile browser correctly, but I get `'User Denied Geolocation' error` testing on mobile devices.

What could be the reasons of this error?

If it helps, i'm using chrome in my mobile device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is exactly what the error message says: `'User denied Geolocation'`. You have to change your mobile browser's privacy settings to grant your OpenLayers web page access to the geolocation.